Airflow cannot find google-generativeai library
I'm using Airflow 2.10.2. I already installed the google-generativeai==0.8.3 library in docker-compose (I already checked it by pip list command and it was).
_PIP_ADDITIONAL_REQUIREMENTS: ${_PIP_ADDITIONAL_REQUIREMENTS:- google-generativeai google-auth aiohttp}
But however I still got this error:
Broken DAG: \[/opt/airflow/dags/news_gpt_dag.py\]
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "\<frozen importlib.\_bootstrap\>", line 488, in \_call_with_frames_removed
File "/opt/airflow/dags/news_gpt_dag.py", line 10, in \<module\>
import google.generativeai as genai
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google.generativeai'

How can I import this library in the right way?

py -m pip install google-generativeai  Released: Oct 7, 2024
